# Customized templates on "New" button only show up on current site/library context and not all of the organization sites/libraries

Tags: document, custom, office, template, button

When you navigate to a document library, there is a "New" button that lets you add folders or regular brand new Office files to said library. In this "New" button, you can add your own custom Office templates (e. g. a Word file with my company logo on it).

However, when I add those custom templates, they only appear in the context of the current site, and not all company sites.

Things I already tried:

1. Setting up an Organization Assets Library: the uploaded templates show up when I create a new Office file from office.com, but not on the "New" button of a library;
2. Content Type publishing from Content Type Hub: the office templates do get distributed to all sites, but I have to manually "allow content types" on site configurations and then apply the new content type to each library in every single site.

Of course I could just teach people creating sites to follow the procedures in item 2, but I'm dealing with end users that really struggle with technology.

Is there a way of making this process automatic for all sites within my company hub?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a mixture of a Site Design Template and a Content type hub to achieve this goal.

Firstly add the content type into the content type hub and in the advanced settings you will be able to upload a custom template for the content type. Once you have done that you will have to create a JSON Site Design Template to call down that specific Content Type and it will be automatically applied to the library you reference. I have added a sample of what the JSON should look like below:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/site-design-script-actions.schema.json",
    "actions": [
        {
            "verb": "setRegionalSettings",
            "timeZone": 2,
            "locale": 2057,
            "hourFormat": "24",
            "sortOrder": 25
        },
        {
            "verb": "activateSPFeature",
            "featureId": "d95c97f3-e528-4da2-ae9f-32b3535fbb59",
            "scope": "web"
        },
        {
            "verb": "activateSPFeature",
            "featureId": "3bae86a2-776d-499d-9db8-fa4cdc7884f8",
            "scope": "site"
        },
        {
            "verb": "activateSPFeature",
            "featureId": "b50e3104-6812-424f-a011-cc90e6327318",
            "scope": "site"
        },
        {
            "verb": "addContentTypesFromHub"
        },
        {
            "verb": "createSPList",
            "listName": "FOI",
            "templateType": 101,
            "addNavLink": true,
            "subactions": [
                {
                    "verb": "addContentType",
                    "name": "Document",
                    "id": "0x0101"
                },
                {
                    "verb": "addContentType",
                    "name": "Folder",
                    "id": "0x0120"
                },


After this you will need to upload that JSON file as a Site Script and then a Site Design and it should work for you.
```